# Error when i call web3 api to sell and buy my ERC20 tokens in ReactJs

Tags: nextjs

I have a ERC20 token and I have created a smart Contract to buy and sell my tokens. I have also created a front end to buy and sell my tokens. Now I want to create an API to sell and buy my tokens. With some reference I have created the code below for buying the tokens. But I am not able to understand how I mention the url for my API and how to test it in postman . My contract is in goerli faucet .

My API code:

buy_Tokens.js:

```
import {ethers} from 'ethers';
import { tokenSwapAddress } from "../../../config";
import tokenSwapAbi from '../../../artifacts/contracts/Tokenswap.sol/TokenSwap.json';
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal';

export default async function handler(req,res){
    if(req.method === 'POST'){
        const {numberOfTokens} = req.body;

        //Check if data is present
        if(numberOfTokens === undefined || numberOfTokens === ''|| numberOfTokens === 0){
            res.status(400).json({success: false, msg: 'Number of tokens is required.'});
            return;
        }
        //connect to user wallet
        const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
        const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const feePercent = 3;
        const tokenPrice = 0.0168;

        //Set up contract instance 
        const tokenSwapContract = new ethers.Contract(tokenSwapAddress,tokenSwapAbi.abi,signer);
        
        //Calculating total fee amount to pay
        const numberOfTokensinNum = Number(numberOfTokens)
        const numberOftokensinWei = ethers.utils.parseEther(String(numberOfTokens))
        const totalfee = (numberOfTokensinNum * feePercent)/100;
        const totalAmount = (numberOfTokensinNum - totalfee) * tokenPrice
        const totalAmountinWei = ethers.utils.parseEther(String(totalAmount))

        //Buy tokens
        try{
           const tx = await tokenSwapContract.buyTokens(numberOftokensinWei,{
            value: totalAmountinWei,
            gasLimit: 5000000
           })
           await tx.wait();
           res.status(200).json({success: true, msg:'Transaction Successful.'})
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).json({success: false, msg:'Transaction Failed. Please try again.'})
        }
    }else{
        res.status(400).json({success: false, msg: 'Bad request.'})
    }
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: I am not sure how to access this code.  How to declare the url for this api and how to test it in postman?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm pretty sure this isn't an ethereum question.
To be able to access your API you need to run and host your code on a server or could service, then access host through postman/code/browser.

you could search online for `how to host node.js code`.
your code is also missing a gateway for communicating with the blockchain, web3Modal can help but you're missing so info for it as well.